# SystemD-JournalD Loses Track of Previous Boot Persistent Log Data

Tags: linux, systemd, embedded, systemd-journald, journalctl

I am running SystemD JournalD version 244.3 on a custom Embedded Linux board.

```
root@board:/var/log/journal# journalctl --version
systemd 244 (244.3+)
-PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS -ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 -IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

My /etc/systemd/journald.conf file is configured to save persistent logs:

```
root@board:/var/log/journal# cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf 
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
SystemMaxFileSize=10M
SystemMaxFiles=6
SystemMaxUse=64M
SystemKeepFree=64M
SyncIntervalSec=60
RateLimitBurst=0
RateLimitInterval=0s
ForwardToSyslog=no
```

I can see that JournalD has persistently saved previous boots under /var/log/jounal:

```
root@board:/var/log/journal# ls -rlt
total 8
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 17:40 ffc9c0e961a74d3b8d19a6f32a5f62ce
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 17:40 10fab8e697104bfeb2f769b11cf42473
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 17:40 c9b5b0b8d10a48f68bda02db47bd3998
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 20:36 0cdee57054ba49a3a75ee9f21d5afbce
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 20:47 7b38f3dd12484f9f82e1d9fc686bc3fe
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 22 22:58 3315ac28810449538f2637d56d3ff707
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 23 13:56 d9fb69f615b04b69998bd5dc70af7b0f
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal 1024 Jul 23 14:29 46e633c0af784239b02f8d230125ee9b
```

In order to view these logs, I have to explicitely use the "-D" flag of journalctl:

```
journalctl -D /var/log/journal -m
```

And to view the newest first, throw the "-r" flag in there

```
journalctl -D /var/log/journal -m -r
```

The problem I see is that journalctl does not seem to know about these previous boots without pointing it to the directory with "-D"!

```
root@board:/var/log/journal# journalctl --list-boots
0 7da269c106be4979bd54bf1f06e6106a Thu 2020-07-23 14:29:50 UTC—Thu 2020-07-23
 14:53:51 UTC
```

There is only 1 boot listed - the others are ignored.

Also, journalctl does not have an accounting of the disk space used by the previous boots. It only tracks the current boot.

```
root@board:/var/log/journal# journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 8.0M in the file system.
```

This is the biggest problem, because the daemon itself does not cleanup previous boot data as it seems to have lost track of it.

How can I make JournalD consider previous boot data for log rotation and viewing of boots with "--list-boots". Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem on my raspberry pi. I also have to add the -D option. I have systemd 215. Have you found something yourself?

Comment: No - I have not figured this out. Interesting that you see the same thing. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Are you using a read only rootfs? It looks like your /etc/machine-id is changing.